# Android String date "2017-09-04T07:09:30.269+00:00" convert to long

Tags: android, android-date

I received the date string from the notification server in the following format.
**2017-09-04T07:09:30.269+00:00**

I want it to convert to long to save in database.

```
public static long convertStringDatetoLong(final String date, final String inputFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
        try {
            Date outputDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            return outputDate.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Then i call `convertStringDatetoLong(date, "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");`
But i found that the convert long is somehow wrong.

The result time is 1483513770269 which is wrong. 
it should be sometimes like 1504509270911 which is start with 15... (which i got with currentTimeMillis)

**2017-09-04T07:09:30.269+00:00**, the input time zone is not the same as My time zone which is GMT+08:00

I don't know how to convert it to the device time zone and get the correct milliseconds to save.

**Updated:**

Sorry that i am doing stupid thing. it should be MM not mm.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the Object `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```
String example = "2017-09-04T07:09:30.269+00:00";
OffsetDateTime offset = OffsetDateTime.parse(example);
ZonedDateTime result = offset.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.systemDefault() ); // Put you wanted zone here
```

From there on you can easily get the timestamp as millis with this line of code:

```
Long timestamp = startTime.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
```

Comment: This required API 26.  I need to support lower level API > 16.

Comment: Oh ok that wasn't written anywhere so I expected to use a high API level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String timeStr = "2017-09-04T07:09:30.269+00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date Obj= null;
try {
    Obj = sdf.parse(timeStr);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

long time = Obj.getTime();
System.out.println(time);
```